# Find the most popular month for customers to order a certain product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find out which month has the most orders for a certain product (Product HHYDP). This is my code so far, but each time I try to use GROUP BY and SORT BY functions related to my problem, I get an error. There are three years in the database (2006,2007,2008) and they are formatted as (YYYY-MM-DD). I am trying to find which month has the highest total order volume across the three years, quantity is irrelevant.

```
SELECT p.productname, o.orderdate
FROM [Sales].[Orders] as o
    JOIN [Sales].[OrderDetails] as od
        ON o.orderid = od.orderid
    JOIN [Production].[Products] as p
        ON od.productid = p.productid
WHERE p.productname like '%hhydp%'
```

I am using microsoft SQL management server.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih I am using Microsoft SQL management server
   ` product name       order date `
   ` Product HHYDP   2006-08-20 `
   `Product HHYDP   2006-08-30 `
   ` Product HHYDP   2007-07-27 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `year` and `month` with `COUNT` aggregate function function and add them in `group by`

```
SELECT p.productname,
       year(o.orderdate) yr,
       month(o.orderdate) mn,
       COUNT(*) cnt
FROM [Sales].[Orders] as o
    JOIN [Sales].[OrderDetails] as od
        ON o.orderid = od.orderid
    JOIN [Production].[Products] as p
        ON od.productid = p.productid
WHERE p.productname like '%hhydp%'
GROUP BY p.productname, year(o.orderdate) ,month(o.orderdate)
```

Comment: This works - my issue was that I was only putting the entire order date in the SELECT statement instead of choosing year and month separately.